# Redshift create table Distkey with more than column error

Tags: sorting, indexing, database-design, amazon-redshift

This statement to create a table in redshift:

```
create table scoresc
distkey (metrics_id, scorefactors_id, tips_id)
compound sortkey (metrics_id, scorefactors_id, tips_id, expor_timestamp)
as select * from scores;
```

===
why it errors?
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:

```
create table scoresc
distkey (metrics_id, scorefactors_id, tips_id)
compound sortkey (metrics_id, scorefactors_id, tips_id, export_timestamp...

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "," 
Position: 46;

distkey (metrics_id, scorefactors_id, tips_id)
```

=============
redshift documentations do not provide examples on `DISTKEY` with multi columns

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you're trying to do with that, but you can only distribute on one key. The idea of the distkey is to provide a method of evenly splitting a table across all nodes within a cluster, multiple distribution keys wouldn't make too much sense in that.

Try just using one distkey instead, whichever one would partition most evenly across your cluster

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no key that fits this criteria. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you.  That was my thought as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you're absolutely sure you need to distribute by all these columns you can create an additional concatenated key column by combining these columns with some delimiter like

`metrics_id||'-'||scorefactors_id||'-'||tips_id`

and use that as a dist key for your table.